# How to get "xdotool windowsize" to resize a window across two monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, resize, xdotool

I have two monitors side-by-side. I can manually resize a window to span across the two monitors. However, I am not able to automate this action using "xdotool". It appears that I can resize the window to at most the size of one monitor, but no more.

Any idea of how to proceed?

[Edit]
I have two screens, side by side, both rotated vertically, and
I have tried running (asumming 77594629 is the ID of the window):

```
    xdotool windowmove 77594629 0 0
    xdotool windowsize 77594629 2156 1868
```

Yet, the size bounds appear to be instead capped at the size of one monitor.

Comment: Would you please add which command you tried exactly? Thanks.

Comment: Please see my edit above for the commands.

Comment: Checked. Not working here, as you describe. Sometime with very big values I can obtain the windows spanning the two screens, but it's erratically at best. Seems a bug...